# How to count rows while fitting some rules

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is the following data frame `df`:

```
df = 

ID_DATA   FD_1   FD_2   FD_3   FD_4   GRADE
111       23     12     34     45     1
111       23     67     45            5
111       12     67     45     23     5
222       23     55     66            4
222       55     66                   4
```

I calculated the frequency per `ID_DATA` as follows:

```
freq = df.ID_DATA.value_counts().reset_index()

freq =

ID_DATA  FREQ
111      3
222      2
```

However, I need to change the logic of this calculation as follows. There are two lists with different values of `FD_*`:

```
BaseList = [23,34]
AdjList = [12,45,67]
```

I need to count the frequency of the occurrence of values from these two lists in `df`. But there are some rules:

1) If a row contains any value of `FD_*` that belongs to `AdjList`, then `BaseList` should not be counted. The counting of `BaseList` should only be done if a row does not contain any value from `AdjList`.

2) If a row contains multiple values of `BaseList`, then it should be counted as +1.

3) If a row contains multiple values of `AdjList`, then only the last column `FD_*` should be counted.

The result should be this one:

```
ID_DATA    FREQ_BaseList    FREQ_12   FREQ_45   FREQ_67
111        0                0         3         0
222        1                0         0         0
```

The value of `FREQ_BaseList` is equal to 0 for `111`, because of firing the rule #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to create custom function for this and then adjust it as needed. You can of course make it a bit more pretty by replacing hardcoded lists of columns:

```
>>> def worker1(x):
...      b = 0
...      for v in x:
...          if v in AdjList:
...              return ['FREQ_' + str(int(v)), 1]
...          else:
...              b = b + BaseList.count(v)
...      return ('FREQ_BaseList', b)
... 
>>> def worker2(x):
...     r = worker1(x[['FD_4','FD_3','FD_2','FD_1']])
...     return pd.Series([x['ID_DATA'], r[1]], index=['ID_DATA', r[0]])
...
>>> res = df.apply(worker2, axis=1).groupby('ID_DATA').sum()
>>> res
         FREQ_45  FREQ_BaseList
ID_DATA                        
111.0        3.0            NaN
222.0        NaN            1.0
>>> res.reindex(columns=['FREQ_BaseList','FREQ_12','FREQ_45','FREQ_67']).fillna(0).astype(int)
         FREQ_BaseList  FREQ_12  FREQ_45  FREQ_67
ID_DATA                                          
111.0                0        0        3        0
222.0                1        0        0        0
```